# Stuck with react browser console write: "App.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input at App.gettingcovid"

Tags: reactjs, fetch

Where is a problem? Browser writes:

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
> at App.gettingcovid

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  gettingcovid = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault ();
   
    const codata = await 
    fetch(' https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/casedistribution/json/', {
      mode : 'no-cors',
    });
    const data = await codata.json();
    console.log(data);
  }
  

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <Covid />
        <Form coviddata={this.gettingcovid}/>
        <Infected />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response. Site *opendata.ecdc.europa.eu* will not accept requests from other sites.

Adding `mode: 'no-cors'` will not magically bypass security :) You might need a backend for downloading the data and then serving it to you page.

Comment: How add a json directly in project?